# IE8 reporting its user agent string as IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, windows-xp, user-agent, ie8-compatibility-mode

I've got a curious problem with a friend's computer.  Although I've verified he's using `Internet Explorer 8.0.6001.18702` on Windows XP (up to date with all things from Microsoft Update).

However, here is the user agent string it reports:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C)
```

This is bizarre for a number of reasons:

- IE8 is reporting that it's IE9.  The `Trident/4.0` definitely verifies that it's IE8.  This is referenced by the official Microsoft documentation on the user agent string:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx
- I've only ever seen `Mozilla/5.0` in the user agent string for actual versions of IE9.

I'm stumped.  We've done a reset of IE (KB923737 at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737), I've disabled all extensions/addons inside IE, and there doesn't seem to be anything installed that would be purposefully altering the user agent string.  I've also dug into the registry to see if the user agent string is being spoofed, and it is at the default (unaltered).

Anyone have any ideas of what I should look at or try next...or what might be responsible for IE8's apparent identity crisis?

Answer (score 0):

We had a customer with the same issue.  Also stumped.  We changed to using TRIDENT as well as the MSIE number to accurately detect what they were using.

If they are using Trident 4, it is either IE 8 (or IE 7 because of compat mode) but nothing higher.  Same for other versions of IE as well.  Trident 5 can't be higher than IE 9, etc.